# API to do arithmetic operations on pointers (cl_mem)

Tags: opencl

My ultimate goal is to do arithmetic operations on pointers on the host side. I know that we can do the following on the kernels:

```
// .cl file
__kernel void pointerAdd(float* arr, int index, float newVal) {
    *(arr + index) = newVal;
}

// .cpp file
cl_mem arr = clCreateBuffer(...);
opencl.run("pointerAdd", {1} /* GWS */, {1} /* LWS */, arr, 10, 2.2f);
```

But, can I increment the pointer on the host before passing it to the kernel?

Since OpenCL buffers are represented by objects (i.e., `cl_mem`), doing `arr += 10;` on the host is completely wrong. Is there an API that we can use to do pointer arithmetic?

Comment: The pointers are only meaningful on the OpenCL device, so I doubt there's an API for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create sub-buffer objects which reference a subrange of an existing buffer using [`clCreateSubBuffer`](http://man.opencl.org/clCreateSubBuffer.html) and therefore can be used to pass a pointer to a specific position within the larger buffer to a kernel.

However, these sub-buffers have some fairly stringent alignment restrictions (see docs) so they are likely not terribly useful for arbitrary pointer arithmetic.

By far the easiest way to do this kind of thing is to simply pass an additional index/offset argument to the kernel and perform the offset operation there.